# HTML: MaterializeCss: Icon Section - Image instead of Icon?

Tags: html, css

I have a Question:

I´m using this template from MaterializeCss:

http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html

As you can see, there are 3 Icon section on this page, with three different icons.

My Question: Is there a way to replace this icons with a image (.png)

This is the code for the first Icon in the Icon Section:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">flash_on</i></h2>
        <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

        <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I already tried it like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="icon-block">
       // HERE IS THE NEW PART 
        <img src="img/pic1.png" height="142" width="142">
        <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

        <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But unfortunately the image is not shown centered...

Comment: Could be that its not what your looking for, but at randyvroegop.nl I used materialize and I think I got what you want. Cant send you details over my phone but you can probably zee for yourself. Just use the grid for 4 width instead of 3.

Comment: Thank you!! Thats exactly what i was looking for!! :)

Comment: But if i add specific sizes to the image, the image is not centered again.. For example: height="142" width="142"

Comment: Create a div instead of the image at that location and pass over the classes the image would het to the div. let the div have 'text-align center' and insert the pic there. You could give it a top padding as well if you'd like.